# Dojo require AMD modules debugging IE9

Tags: javascript, debugging, dojo, requirejs, internet-explorer-9

Recently an app I'm working on made the move from an old dojo version 1.2 up to 1.8
While using dojo 1.2, RequireJS was used to load modules.

The problem with dojo's require seems to be that it is using XHR+eval for script files, while RequireJS loaded the scripts in some other way, perhaps tags?

This have made debugging in IE9 really hard as the source files cannot be found, since they are eval'd and anonymous. Firebug (1.12.4) seems to have this issue aswell, but randomly.

It also makes finding the script errors really hard since they are somewhere in dojo.js.

Is there any way to have dojo load non-dojo modules using the RequireJS pattern?
Dojo version can not be changed and going back to RequireJS is not really the best option either. Are there any tools to make debugging easier in IE9? Really need to view those script files.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo's AMD loader absolutely supports asynchronous loading via script injection - that was a big point of migrating to AMD.

You just need to add `async: true` to your `dojoConfig` to switch it into fully-async mode.  By default it's not, for backwards-compatibility.